# How to make the icon of a bottom tab navigator fit inside the tab bar?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using a bottomTabNavigator in my React Native app. I'm using an  component as an icon. Is is possible to make it fit inside the tab (with padding) without explicitly defining a size?

If not, is there some constant in which I can get the tab bar height?

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

and this is my tabBarIcon code:

```
/**
 * 
 */
import React from 'react';
import {
    Image,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

export default class TabMenuIcon extends React.Component {

    static SCREENS = {
        SOCIAL: "s",
        CALCULATION: "c",
        CONFIGURE: "d"
    };

    render() {

        const { focused, tintColor, size, which } = this.props;

        switch(which) {
            case TabMenuIcon.SCREENS.SOCIAL:
                return <Image source={require('../assets/icons/tabsocial.png')} style={style.img} />
                break;
            case TabMenuIcon.SCREENS.CALCULATION:
                return <Image source={require('../assets/icons/tabcalculations.png')} style={style.img} />
                break;
            case TabMenuIcon.SCREENS.CONFIGURE:
                return <Image source={require('../assets/icons/tabconfigure.png')} style={style.img} />
                break;
            default:
                return <Text>t</Text>
        }
    }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    img: {
        padding:6, // Does nothing??
        margin: 4, // Does nothing??
    }
});
```

Comment: why dont you add height:10, width :10 in your img style?

Comment: @GauravRoy I don't want to hardcode a value, since it might change in the future. I wouldn't mind using a constant set by the react-native-tabs package, though.

Comment: no nee to hardcode, just check if its fitting , the what you can do is do dimensions.height *  10/dimensions.height , hope its clear. you can ask doubts

Comment: @GauravRoy Can you explain? Which variable is dimensions? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What im saying is dont hardcode the image height, rather you can check for the height of image in your simulator, and suppose you give height and width to be 10.

It fits perfectly suppose. Then to ensure that just giving 10 doesnt break my image in other phones which has different screen resolution you can do ,

```
height = (10/640) * deviceHeight
width = (10/360) * deviceWidth.
```

here im assuminb your phone height and width are 640 and 360 respectively.

you can get device height and width by :

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native;
deviceWidth =  Dimensions.get('window').width,
deviceHeight=  Dimensions.get('window').height
```

hope it clears